# pandas.DataFrame.assign: how to refer to newly created columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use `pandas.DataFrame.assign` in Pandas 1.5.2. Let's consider this code, for instance:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3], "col2": [4,5,6]})
df.assign(
    test1="hello",
    test2=df.test1 + " world"
)
```

I'm facing this error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'test1'

However, it's explicitly stated [in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) that:

> Assigning multiple columns within the same `assign` is possible. Later items in `**kwargs` may refer to newly created or modified columns in `df`; items are computed and assigned into `df` in order.

So I don't understand: **how can I refer to newly created or modified columns in `df` when calling `assign`**?

Comment: Use a lambda: `test2=lambda d: d.test1 + " world"`

Comment: Thank you, and is there any way to avoid using a callable in this case? `assign` is supposed to accept `Series` parameters

Comment: Not if you want to chain the assignments.

Comment: The documentation wasn't very clear on that point but your answer is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a callable to [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html). Here use a lambda to reference the DataFrame.

> Parameters
> ****kwargsdict of {str: callable or Series}**
>
> The column names are keywords. **If the values are callable, they are computed on the DataFrame and
> assigned to the new columns.** The callable must not change input
> DataFrame (though pandas doesn’t check it). If the values are not
> callable, (e.g. a Series, scalar, or array), they are simply assigned.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3], "col2": [4,5,6]})

df.assign(
    test1="hello",
    test2=lambda d: d.test1 + " world"
)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  test1        test2
0     1     4  hello  hello world
1     2     5  hello  hello world
2     3     6  hello  hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

You can crete new columns like ```df['new']= df.col1 + something

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3], "col2": [4,5,6]})
df['test1'] = "hello"
df['test2']=df.test1 + " world"
df
```

Comment: Indeed, but my question was specifically about `assign` to benefit from chaining

Comment: Ok then @mozway 's answer is the one you want.